# How to pass output as arguments to another command?

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe, gnome

I am using a command,

```
gsettings2 monitor org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri| cut -f2 -d "'"
```

This correctly gives uri for changed wallpapers.
I want to pipe every such value to a function foo such that

```
function foo {
    echo "Value changed $1"
}
```

executes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gsettings2 ... | stdbuf -oL cut -f2 -d "'" | while read -r uri; do
    foo "$uri"
done
```

The `while read` loop calls `foo` for each URI it reads. The `stdbuf -oL` call is there to force `cut` to be line-buffered so its output is visible immediately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I was trying this myself but this isn't working for some reason. Updated question. Please note that [gsettings monitor](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gsettings-tool.html) is itself an infinite loop.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if cut is working, why isn't this.

Comment: Does it help if you do `stdbuf -oL cut -f2 -d "'"`? The problem might be that `cut`'s output is fully buffered. If stdbuf helps let me know and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Phew, I never realized that `cut`might be the problem.